# Why is AudioManager leaking?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, android-audiomanager

i`m facing this memory leak after closing my activity by pressing back-button:
[image]

Since i couldnt figure out what it is, i outcommented almost my whole code to:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
}

protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

I guess it has something to do with AudioManager. But since i outcommented anything i dont have a clue what it could be.

Any advice?

**Update:**
I`m facing the same "issue" while making a heap dump on a hello-world app, created by android studio.....so i guess its somehow normal. But whats the explanation for this?

Answer (score 1):

Even you are not using `AudioManager`, it might leak as some of the buttons in your UI might yield a click sound. For some reason, it might or might not leak.

A working solution for me was to use the workaround that can be found [on github](https://gist.github.com/jankovd/891d96f476f7a9ce24e2). Further discussion is available here: [Android Context Memory Leak ListView due to AudioManager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6445052/375209)